# SharePoint 2007 account password update

Tags: 2007

I have 4 servers in SharePoint 2007 farm and having single account for complete farm.
When I changed the password for the account and after below steps:
on CA servers: stsadm -o updatefarmcredentials -userlogin "domain\id" -password "password"

on other SP servers: stsadm -o updatefarmcredentials -userlogin "domain\id" -password "password" -local

Timer job "Administration Application Pool Credential Deployment" created and took approx. 3 hours to disappears. 
Is there any reason to take long time.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved after clear the SharePoint configuration cache on all server and within seconds timer job disappeared.